# ElasticSearch - Aggregations without any bucketing

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to get aggregations without any bucketing specification?

For example, I'd like to get the SUM of a numeric value of all documents in a collection.

In SQL: `SELECT SUM(FIELD), COUNT(*) FROM TABLE;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply specify a top-level [`sum` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "total": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "myField"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get an answer like this

```
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": 48441987,               <---- COUNT(*)
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "total": {
      "value": 445420187457          <---- SUM(FIELD)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `sum` aggregation returns buckets? How might I get `sum` by bucketing?

Comment: Didn't you ask for no bucketting? The sum aggregation is a metric aggregation and only returns a number. What buckets do you want?

Comment: Sorry! I answered me well. I ask you for another question. I've took a look on [documentation] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html), and I see I might use `sum_bucket`. However, what about using sub-aggregations? term(field) -> sum? So I'm going to ask for it on a new post.